# Convert a prefix to a suffix while dealing with multiple underscores

Tags: r, variables, conditional-statements, prefix, suffix

How to convert a prefix to a suffix when variable names can have multiple underscores?
Some variable names have 1 underscore, some have 3. Assuming the prefix is always the beginning of the string to the first underscore, how can I pivot these variable names upon their 1st underscore? And vice versa (suffix back to prefix).

```
Vars <- c("Low_pq", "High_pq", "Low_total_acid_number", "High_total_acid_number")
Vars
```

The code below accurately reverses variable names with 1 underscore, but fails on ones with multiple underscores, they remain unchanged.

```
Vars <- str_replace(Vars, "^([^_]*)_([^_]*)$", "\\2_\\1")
Vars
```

**The desired result is;**

"pq_Low"  "pq_High", "total_acid_number_Low"  "total_acid_number_High"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex pattern is slightly off, and you should be using `.*` after the first underscore to capture all remaining content:

```
Vars <- str_replace(Vars, "^([^_]*)_(.*)$", "\\2_\\1")
```

### Demo

Comment: Wow, what an awesome tool. And how to convert it back from a suffix to the original prefix?

Comment: Maybe: `str_replace(Vars, "^(.*)_(.*)$", "\\2_\\1")` ?  Try it and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sub` in base R :

```
sub('(.*?)_(.*)', '\\2_\\1', Vars)
#[1] "pq_Low"    "pq_High"  "total_acid_number_Low"  "total_acid_number_High"
```